# How do I get this async lambda to compile without adding unreachable code?

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a method:

```
void MyMethod<T>(params Func<T>[] funcs) { }
```

I want to call it with async lambdas:

```
MyMethod(async () => 1, async () => 2, async () => 3);
```

It works! But what if I want the third lambda to throw an exception?

```
MyMethod(async () => 1, async () => 2, async () => { throw new Exception(); });
```

The above doesn't compile, it gives two identical errors:

> CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as statements

I'm not sure why it gives this error, but I understand why it can't compile - the first two lambdas are `Func<Task<int>>` while the last is `Func<Task>`. I'd expect it to give me a better compilation error, but let's put this problem aside.

How do I get the code to compile? I'd probably have to tell the compiler what type of task I'd like to generate for the third async lambda. One way I found is to specify a `return` statement after the `throw` statement:

```
MyMethod(async () => 1, async () => 2, async () => { throw new Exception(); return 3; });
```

Aside from being ugly and confusing, it generates a compiler warning:

> CS0162 Unreachable code detected

**How do I make the compiler happy? How do I avoid unreachable code just to make it compile? Is there another way to specify the task type to be returned by an async lambda?**

*<sup>Also, why do I get a CS0201 error in the above example?</sup>*

Comment: Why are you using async lambdas in the first place, given that you're not using `await`?

Comment: @Servy: Actual code does use awaits. There is even an await in the third lambda that throws an exception. This is a stripped down version of the code.

Comment: Then provide an example that's actually representative of your actual code.

Comment: Providing the async keyword does not make your code async.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler infers your `T` to be `Task` because the last lambda has no return type.

It therefore tries to parse the first lambdas as having no return value, which means they must be valid as statements, not expressions.  Since `1` is not valid as a statement, you this weird-sounding error.

To make your code compile, explicitly pass the generic type parameter:

```
MyMethod<Task<int>>(async () => 1, async () => 2, async () => { throw new Exception(); });
```

[example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AKgBYBOqAhgCb5k0gDWIO2ADsAEYA2YAMYxBfZiBgBhGAG9sMBTABuAezB0YAWQSbUyciroAeUgD4AFJxqUa6CQDFgEQSdMBtALowAZk8EgASlkYAF95RW5+IWU1DU1zILltXX1DE2YWI0hkUwtmBGcYBJgAXlMYAEYAGhh8wuKymAAmGrrhBvKZGH1KFQB3GAhUAYBRAA9BVE5kMBUIBMxQgJxFUOwQoA===)

Comment: I can't remove `async` as the actual code does use awaits in the lambdas. There is even an await in the third lambda that throws an exception. This is a stripped down version of the code.

Comment: Even with the example as is, removing `async` changes the semantics.

Comment: I was wrong; this is not a compiler bug.  I added a full explanation.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks. Simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

The lambda in your first example won't be of `Func<Task<int>>` (without context, it'll be `Action`), but it's a valid lambda for that delegate.  Since it is valid for the delegate that you want, just cast it to that:

```
MyMethod(async () => 1, 
    async () => 2, 
    (Func<Task<int>>)(async () => { throw new Exception(); }));
```

Comment: Not quite; if that were the problem, he'd get an invalid conversion error.  The real problem is in the other lambdas because of that inference.